# Display incoming JMS message in a browser

Tags: java, servlets, jms

We work with external system using request-response communication model via JMS.

Suppose, a user sends a request message to one queue from his browser (by navigating to some URL mapped to a corresponding servlet). Then, there is an MDB which asynchronously receives a message on another JMS queue. Is there a way to then get back to the user who originated the request and show that message in his browser in the same session?

The only thing that comes to mind so far is to save this response in a database. Then, the servlet which initially triggered the request would wait until the data is available and display it as soon as possible.

But is there any other clean way without using intermediary storage to achieve that?

**UPDATE**

The request and response queues are different. The only connection between them is that the response contains the same JMS `correlationID` as in request.

Comment: The servlet posts to the first queue. What is the relation between that event and an MDB receiving the message on anothe queue? Is the same queue and does the MDB receive the message posted by the Servlet ? Or is it an entirely different thing? Sorry your question is not clear.

Comment: Something like the `Request&Reply pattern` described [here](http://www.eaipatterns.com/RequestReplyJmsExample.html)

Comment: @Matteo Please, re-read the question, or at least its title. I'm not asking about how to properly implement request/response pattern. The problem is that I'm only able to print the response in the log, whereas I would like to display it in a browser to a user who originated the request.

Comment: i think you are doing the best thing by saving the response in the database , and check @ramp solution , i think from your jsp send ajax requests to check the database and update the UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you can get around storing the response in db. We do something similar in our application where we attach the correlation id to the session and the browser makes ajax calls to check for the response update in the db. Has scaled pretty well for us so far.

The rqeuest response nature of http does not go hand in hand with async message processing. I have not experimented with stuff like WebSockets though.

Comment: I agree. This is the final solution that I came to. Had no time to explore the WebSockets option, but I think it's not going to work. If I manage to come up with something more elegant, I'll post the solution. Thanks for your input.